# Grep title of a page which is written with spaces

Tags: bash, awk, grep, metadata, title

I am trying to get the meta title of some website...

some people write title like

```
`<title>AllHeart Web INC, IT Services Digital Solutions Technology
</title>
`

`<title>AllHeart Web INC, IT Services Digital Solutions Technology</title>`

`<title>
AllHeart Web INC, IT Services Digital Solutions Technology
</title>`
```

some like more ways... my current focus on above 3 ways...

I wrote a simple code, it only capture 2nd way of title written, but i am not sure how can I grep the other ways,

```
`curl -s https://allheartweb.com/ | grep -o '<title>.*</title>'`
```

I also made a code (very bad i guess)

where i can grep number of line like

```
`
% curl -s https://allheartweb.com/ | grep -n '<title>'                   
7:<title>AllHeart Web INC, IT Services Digital Solutions Technology

% curl -s https://allheartweb.com/ | grep -n '</title>' 
8:</title>
`
```

and store it and run loop to get title item... which i guess a bad idea...

any help I can get all possible of getting title?

Comment: Why don't you use XmlLint? https://xmllint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -s https://allheartweb.com/ | tr -d '\n' | grep -m 1 -oP '(?<=<title>).+?(?=</title>)'
```

You can remove newlines from HTML via `tr` because they have no meaning in the title. The next step returns the first match of the shortest string enclosed in `<title>` `</title>`.

This is quite a simple approach of course. `xmllint` would be better but that's not available to all platforms by default.

Answer (score 0):

'grep' is not a very good tool to match multiple lines. It is processing line-by-line. You could hack that by making your incoming text one line like

```
curl -s https://allheartweb.com/ | xargs | grep -o -E "<title>.*</title>"
```

This is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sed`:

```
curl -s https://allheartweb.com/ | sed -n "{/<title>/,/<\/title>/p}"
```